# Android sdk location while installing android studio on different drive

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to reinstall android studio. Previously it was on the C drive and now I want to install it on another drive, say D.I have completely uninstalled the previous android studio and folders from users/local folder. Now during installation, I am asked to specify the location for SDK. Can I change this from `C:\Users\Cap\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` to any other drive? Will it lead to problems in the future?

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely change the SDK location. I personally prefer to use another drive than `c` for my Android SDK as when I format my c drive and reinstall Android Studio, I don't need to download SDK again. I can simply point my studio to the old location.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  you can install the sdk in any drive you prefer.

Comment: Ok . Can i do the same for components, gradle etc.?

Comment: gradle file auto generated so it will store in particulate folder only

Answer (score 1):

Definitely yes, you can change this location. put sdk file in custom location and set that path, it will not produce any problem.